# Reference to assets from dist folder with vue + webpack in electron app

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron

I am using vuejs + webpack + electron.

I have hard time retrieving the path to my asset.

My project structure is the following:

```
/my-project
  /app
    /components
      componentA.vue
      ...
    App.vue
    main.js
  /dist
    /assets
      /icons
        /a.png
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

I load the static asset in the dist folder with file-loader.

My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'vue-loader',
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ['transform-runtime']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=/assets/icons/[name].[ext]"
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [
      'electron'
    ])
  ],
  node: {
  __dirname: true,
  fs: 'empty',
  module: 'empty',
  net: 'empty',
  tls: 'empty'
},
externals: ["fs"]
}
```

In the file componentA.vue I am trying to do the following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src= "link">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Aa from '../assets/icons/a.png'

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      link: '',

    }
  },

  created() {
    this.link = Aa;
},
   ...
</script>
```

But I have the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///a.png
```

The images appear loaded in the correct path in the dist/assets/icons but electron is trying to load it from

```
file:///assets/icons/a.png
```

I'm new to webpack and tried to load it in different ways but i can't make it work, can you help me in resolving this issue ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yea, thanks for asking! The error log was quite clear, he would look for the image in the wrong path, i solved it by specifing the output path in the webpack config as: 
`output: { publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),`